# Rails new command chmod fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chmod, errno

Chmod seems to be causing a rails new error, here's the specific problem:

```
/home/gossfunkel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': Operation not permitted - /media/windows/Users/gossfunkel/code/rails/blog/script (Errno::EPERM)
```

and here's a pastebin of the full output: http://pastebin.com/SwqxA8bR

Comment: did you install rails or rvm using sudo?

Comment: Does this work by creating your rails project in /tmp ?

Comment: @Intrepidd: this error doesn't occur, but it gives a fatal error about openssh...

Comment: Ok so the first error is probably a problem with permissions, you most likely do not own the directory. What's the ssh error ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8Lxp18C5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running this in `/media/windows` which is presumably an NTFS partition mount. `chmod` is not allowed on NTFS partitions, as NTFS doesn't recognize unix permissions. Run this in your home directory or somewhere that's on a linux partition.